# Get facebook calendar events

Tags: facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, xcode6, facebook-events

I'm trying to get a user's facebook calendar events.
I added the permission user_events, and this is the request I use -

```
var request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"/me/events", parameters: nil);

    request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            println(result["data"]!)
        } else {
            println("Error Getting Friends \(error)");
        }
    }
```

This code doesn't return anything, can you help me fix it?

Thanks!

EDIT

When I checked my upcoming events list it was empty, the data I need is the birthdays in the events/calendar.

Comment: _“the data I need is the birthdays in the events/calendar”_ – those are not actually events, and therefor you can’t get them via `/me/events`. (And not via any other endpoint either.)

Comment: Is there another way to get facebook friends birthdays?

Comment: There is no way to get all friends birthdays. And, even if it was, are you sure the world needs the 1000th birthday app?

Comment: facebook reminds you about friend birthdays anyway ;)

Comment: _“Is there another way to get facebook friends birthdays?”_ – only for friends that have logged in to the app as well, and granted permission to access their birthday.

Answer (score 0):

Have you requested the `user_events` permission upon Login? I guess not...

Comment: I did request the user_events permission